# How to parse JSON object without knowing key using java?

Tags: java, json, parsing

In the below `JSON` object I want to parse without knowing key name.
object also contains another object within it.

> {"status":"ok","description":"Request was
>   successful.","account":{"renewal_upper_limit":0,"id":10066,"email":"raj@gmail.com","full_name":"
>   Raj","phone":"99000000","format_time":"America","format_date":"Asia","reports_time_range":"24
>   hours","dashboard_time_range":"24H"}}

Comment: What do you mean about without knowing key name?

Comment: which JSON parser library are you using?

Comment: You should start by reading Android Docs. http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: not using any library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I iterate JSONObject to get individual items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870332/how-can-i-iterate-jsonobject-to-get-individual-items)

Comment: Do you want to do this without using any library?

Comment: yes. How can I do that?

Comment: How can you identify it without a key name? Are you just looking for any field containing an object?

Comment: Without using any kind of library it will be difficult for you. But Jackson library may help in a easy way to solve this if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json Object is just like a `Map`, you can iterate it like this:

```
    JSONObject parse = JSON.parseObject("");
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : parse.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
    }
```

fastjson is available here:https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson

Comment: MY JSON object also contains another object.How can I detect inner object.

Comment: Just think you inner object as a map, and cast it to JSONObject.

Comment: Json Object --parse--> [Parent Object [Child Object]]