# Storing Json Objects in a List

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to create a list of objects from a JSON object that internally has a lot of different objects. All of the inner objects have the same properties. They look like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "MonkeyKing": {
            "title": "the Monkey King",
            "id": 62,
            "key": "MonkeyKing",
            "name": "Wukong"
        },
        "Jax": {
            "title": "Grandmaster at Arms",
            "id": 24,
            "key": "Jax",
            "name": "Jax"
        },
}
```

The problem is, that I do not want to access the objects using the names, but like I would with a list. 
A Java representation of an object would look like this:

```
public class Champion 
{
    String title;
    int id;
    String key;
    String name;
}
```

So what i want to do is, i want to put those Champion-Objects in a list using Json. My Problem is that i need to use the name of the Object to get them. So is there a way to use Gson to convert the content of the "data"- object to a list?

Comment: write in english please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please translate your question to english so that all members of Stack Overflow are able to read it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "with a list".  Isn't your Java representation "using the names" (i.e. properties)?

Answer (score 1):

You could access the JSON using the keys. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113895/how-to-parse-json-object-without-knowing-key-using-java) for Java code.

```
JSONObject parse = JSON.parseObject("");
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : parse.entrySet()) {
    Champion myChamp = entry.getValue()); // possibly casting necessary
}
```