# How to parse 'HttpServletRequest' with value of key value pair data

Tags: javascript, ajax, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm sending from my client side an ajax request to my server.

this is the data structure that i'm passing:

```
data = {"key1" : "value1" , "key2" : {"subkey1": "subvalue1" ,"subkey2" : "subvalue2"}};
```

on the server side i'm doing the following:

```
   private Map<String, Object> parseItemData(HttpServletRequest request) {

    Enumeration<String> parameterNames = request.getParameterNames();

    while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {

        String paramName = parameterNames.nextElement();

        String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramName);

        if(paramName.equals("itemSpecifics"))
        {
            System.out.println(paramName);

            for (int i =0 ; i<paramValues.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(paramName +": "+paramValues[i] );
            }
        }
    }
    return item;
}
```

this is the output that i'm getting:

```
itemSpecifics: [object Object]
```

is there any way to do it?

---

Solution :

in case of nested key value pair, i had to manual use `JSON.stringify()` for the nested key value in order to send it as `JSON`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may help you.

Use `getParameterMap()` method to get all key value pairs.

```
Map<String, String[]> requestParams = request.getParameterMap();
```

Below code to get JSONObject:

```
JSONObject jsonObject=null;
        Map<String,String> out = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Map<String,String[]> map = request.getParameterMap();

        for (Map.Entry<String,String[]> mapEntry : map.entrySet()) {

          String value[] = mapEntry.getValue();
          Object object = value.length == 1 ? value[0] : value;
          try {
              jsonObject = new JSONObject((String)object);
              parse(jsonObject,out);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
        response.getWriter().print(out);
```

To parse json use parse function  : I have taken help from [How can I iterate JSONObject to get individual items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870332/how-can-i-iterate-jsonobject-to-get-individual-items)

```
public static Map<String,String> parse(JSONObject json , Map<String,String> out) throws JSONException{
        Iterator<String> keys = json.keys();
        while(keys.hasNext()){
            String key = keys.next();
            String val = null;
            try{
                 JSONObject value = json.getJSONObject(key);
                 parse(value,out);
            }catch(Exception e){
                val = json.getString(key);
            }

            if(val != null){
                out.put(key,val);
            }
        }
        return out;
    }
```

Comment: was trying to use it as Map<String, Object> requestParams = request.getParameterMap(); and cast it while having the right key for that, but it cannot cast from string to map 'Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.util.Map'

Comment: for some reason the get action returning string object insted of Object

Comment: getParameterMap() returns  Map<String, String[]> only. iterate through string to get other values using json or jackson library

Comment: Map<String, String[]> requestParams = request.getParameterMap();
JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject)rquestParams.get("itemSpecifics");

By doing that i'm getting the compilation error of Cannot cast from String[] to JSONObject, as the above suggestion..

Comment: I updated code.Please check. or still you facing issue?

Comment: While doing that and printing the 'jsonObject' , i'm getting:
{... , "itemSpecifics":"[object Object]" , ...}

Seems like the data is sent the wrong way?

Comment: Please post actual json.

Comment: Updated Answer and added parse function

Comment: Found the problem , while sending with ajax json with nested key value i have to use JSON.stringify for the nested list other wise the post method will send it as [object Object] and not as json string. Any way your code is working for me :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try this. As `sysout` prints [Object,Object] that means there are two String Objects.

Onw of possible way to declare a String Array like this

`String[] keyValPair = new String[]{"\"key1\" : \"value1\"","key2:{}"}`
This is just a guess how container is parsing this Json like data. May be it converts it in two different String Objects put it as a String Array.

```
    String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramName);

    if(paramName.equals("itemSpecifics"))
    {
     System.out.println(paramName);

     String[] paramArr = (String[]) paramValues[0];
     String firstKeyVal = paramArr [0];//Contains "key1" : "value1" as String
     String secondKeyVal = paramArr [1];//Contains "key2" : {"subkey1": "subvalue1" ,"subkey2" : "subvalue2"} as String

     String value1= firstKeyVal.split(":")[1];
     String[] subValues = secondKeyVal.substring(secondKeyVal.indexOf("{")+1,secondKeyVal.indexOf("}")).split(",");
    String subVal1 = subValues[0].split(":")[1];
    String subVal2 = subValues[1].split(":")[1];

     System.out.println(paramName+" value1"+value1+" subVal1 "+subVal1+" subVal2 "+subVal2);

     }
```

The Best way is to pass all parameters as JSON.

Comment: This is what i'm getting: Cannot cast from String to JSONObject.
any idea?

Comment: @USer22999299 I do not think you are getting a String, you are getting an array of Objects because `sysout` prints `[object Object]`, it does not print String value.Calling `paramValues[i].toString()` will give the same output. Have you tried this approach.

Comment: while applying the code above, i'm getting the compilation error of Cannot cast from String to JSONObject. 
paramValues is a String[]

Comment: @USer22999299 I have updated my answer, by assuming how container will parse this string data.