# How to get multiple specific values from a key in a JSON Object

Tags: java, android, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So right now I am trying to get information from the logged in user through Facebook graph api.

```
{"id":"10202628284866677","name":"Rohit Tigga","link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/app_scoped_user_id\/10202628284866677\/","picture":{"data":{"is_silhouette":false,"url":"https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/hprofile-ak-xta1\/v\/t1.0-1\/p200x200\/10438582_10202555461926149_8285465463541146116_n.jpg?oh=283ec503c6eb051aad077366155c621d&oe=55E6E24B&__gda__=1445616180_3110e5bf89e9f3050fe623b86d47618b"}},"friends":{"data":[{"name":"Arthur Shir","id":"10153237510764181"},{"name":"Kanye East","id":"1454465268197338"}],"paging":{"next":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/v2.3\/10202628284866677\/friends?access_token=CAAWKvUHZCc2sBAHDCZCfL1dHLcrrMoqNxHJSXun5vm1iJQlMxaF43ZCTvIj4Oo4sHeRstTEACDpDz45wLj9FwXBXkoqxPyBQvjcQKY4ZCPgEqhcPdyPb3JepOA1KCADTt2ZBIO8NRX8QKdrlvSWxxgEfSH6SY94nUsLZBRslP8OjJ9r9DYm6kih8GwJ7la0w30KbZAi3AFNOUx1FDU9Y38S&limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=enc_AdB7OPjfCizP7TWz68NToMvADpaegj9bV3w8g22S1dgcGTiHSRUC2xQr2uhJDdQczRtmkKPQS9fzh0Fq7LgWLZAsu"},"summary":{"total_count":1289}}}
```

I was able to get the id, name, profile_pic_url

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(
                                            JSONObject object,
                                            GraphResponse response) {
                                        // Application code
                                        response.getError();
                                        //Here's what you got
                                        Log.e("JSON:", object.toString());

                                        //Find out how to store all user friends efficiently

                                        try {
                                            user_id=object.getString("id");
                                            name=object.getString("name");
                                            profile=object.getString("link");
                                            profile_pic_url = object.getString("picture");
                                            friends = object.getString("friends");


                                            JSONObject pic_object1= (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(profile_pic_url).nextValue();
                                            JSONObject pic_object2 = pic_object1.getJSONObject("data");
                                            profile_pic_url = (String) pic_object2.get("url");
```

I am more specifically trying to get the ID of each facebook friend from the logged in user. It is from this portion which I have as a string now.

```
 {"data":[{"name":"Arthur Shir","id":"10153237510764181"},{"name":"Kanye East","id":"1454465268197338"}],"paging":{"next":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/v2.3\/10202628284866677\/friends?access_token=CAAWKvUHZCc2sBAHDCZCfL1dHLcrrMoqNxHJSXun5vm1iJQlMxaF43ZCTvIj4Oo4sHeRstTEACDpDz45wLj9FwXBXkoqxPyBQvjcQKY4ZCPgEqhcPdyPb3JepOA1KCADTt2ZBIO8NRX8QKdrlvSWxxgEfSH6SY94nUsLZBRslP8OjJ9r9DYm6kih8GwJ7la0w30KbZAi3AFNOUx1FDU9Y38S&limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=enc_AdB7OPjfCizP7TWz68NToMvADpaegj9bV3w8g22S1dgcGTiHSRUC2xQr2uhJDdQczRtmkKPQS9fzh0Fq7LgWLZAsu"},"summary":{"total_count":1289}}
```

I am trying to iterate through the JSON Object and store every id in an array.

But I have been unsuccessful in my attempts.

I am looking at this, yet no luck :/

[How to iterate over a JSONObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151619/java-iterate-over-jsonobject)

[How can I iterate JSONObject to get individual items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870332/how-can-i-iterate-jsonobject-to-get-individual-items)

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your goal is to retrieve the ids from the following json string:

```
{"data":[{"name":"Arthur Shir","id":"10153237510764181"},{"name":"Kanye East","id":"1454465268197338"}],"paging":{"next":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/v2.3\/10202628284866677\/friends?access_token=CAAWKvUHZCc2sBAHDCZCfL1dHLcrrMoqNxHJSXun5vm1iJQlMxaF43ZCTvIj4Oo4sHeRstTEACDpDz45wLj9FwXBXkoqxPyBQvjcQKY4ZCPgEqhcPdyPb3JepOA1KCADTt2ZBIO8NRX8QKdrlvSWxxgEfSH6SY94nUsLZBRslP8OjJ9r9DYm6kih8GwJ7la0w30KbZAi3AFNOUx1FDU9Y38S&limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=enc_AdB7OPjfCizP7TWz68NToMvADpaegj9bV3w8g22S1dgcGTiHSRUC2xQr2uhJDdQczRtmkKPQS9fzh0Fq7LgWLZAsu"},"summary":{"total_count":1289}}
```

In that case, you can try the following code:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray friends = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
for (int index=0; index<friends.length(); ++index){
        JSONObject currentFriend = friends.getJSONObject(index);
        String id = currentFriend.getString("id");
}
```

Comment: have full example ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to grab the JSONArray "data" from the JSON like this

```
JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("data");

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) array.get(i);

    String id = object.get("id");
    //and so on
}
```